# Please ensure you have OWNER-role access to this resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I have a bucket with an object inside it.

```
gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://object-path
```

I get the following error

```
Please ensure you have OWNER-role access to this resource.
```

I am set as the owner of the object when i click the three dots to check and also,

When I run

```
gsutil acl get gs://object-path
```

I get

```
{"email":"ci-tool-access@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
   "entity":"ci-tool-access@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
   "role":"OWNER"
}
```

My IAM permissions for the entire project not just cloud storage resources is set as owner just to repeat myself.  Running

```
gsutil acl get gs://bucket-path
```

gets me this

```
[
  {
    "entity": "project-owners.....",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "...",
      "team": "owners"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  }
]
```

running `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT_ID>`
output:

```
- members:- serviceAccount:ci-tool-access@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com   
role: roles/owner
```

and `gcloud auth list`

```
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       ci-tool-access@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

This is doing my head in, any ideas what might be happening thats preventing me from changing the ACL on the object?  Bucket uniform permissions is set to false so i should have granular access to each object

Comment: For the command `gsutil acl get gs://object-path` where does the output show that the identity that `gsutil` is using has OWNER? What identity is `gsutil` using? User or service account? That identity does not have OWNER.

Comment: gsutil is using the account as authorised in gcloud sdk i get the following output `{
    "email": "ci-tool-access@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "entity": "ci-tool-access@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "role": "OWNER"
  }`

Comment: Show the command that is generating that output. You want to review the output from `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT_ID>`. That determines the roles assigned to an identity for a project.

Comment: the command to get that output is `gsutil acl get gs://object-path` running `gcloud get-iam-policy <PROJECT_ID>` gets me `- members:
  - serviceAccount:ci-tool-access@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/owner`

Comment: The error message is telling you that the identity that you are using does not have OWNER. Double check the identity that gsutil is using. What does `gcloud auth list` show? Look at `YOUR_HOMEDIR/.boto`  file. Review the [Credentials] section - what is configured? Edit your question with the details from your comments.

Comment: i have updated the question with the details.  auth list shows the correct account is being used, there is no .boto file, does that mean it inherits the credentials from the gcloud config?

Comment: There should be a `.boto` file. Provided that you have not configured authorization in .boto` then `gcloud` credentials are used. Are you using a current version of the tools? `gcloud components update` in an elevated prompt (Windows). Maybe you should start over with `gcloud init`.

Comment: Have you filtered output of the command `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT_ID>`? I agree with *@John Hanley*, you should start with `gcloud init` and then try again.